# LINQ from a sql join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to understand how to rewrite a join query in LINQ.

```
SELECT cs.qid,cs.qk FROM location_table pl
JOIN (SELECT qid,qk FROM q_table WHERE att5 = 'process') cs ON pl.qck = cs.qk
WHERE pl.location = 'there'
```

Here is the LINQ I started with but it isn't returning the same results as the above SQL

```
from pl in location_table
from cs in q_table
where s. att5 == 'process'
&& cs.qk == pl.qck
&& pl. location == 'there'
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at the [101 Linq Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9). That link is for joins specifically and will be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `join` keyword

```
from pl in location_table
join cs in q_table
    on cs.qk equals pl.qck
where cs.att5 == ‘process’ && pl. location == ‘there’
select new{cs.qid, cs.qk}
```

If you want to rewrite this as an `EXISTS` since only output from q_table is needed:

```
SELECT qid,qk 
FROM q_table AS cs
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM location_table pl
        WHERE pl.qck = cs.qk AND pl.location = 'there'
    )
    AND cs.att5 == 'process'
```

You would do this:

```
from cs in q_table
where location_table.All(pl=>pl.qck == cs.qk && pl.location == 'there')
    && cs.att5 == 'process'
select new{cs.qid, cs.qk}
```

They should all end up with the same results. I will leave the performance check up to you :)

Comment: Hmmm, now running into a problem of comparing an int to a string cs.qk equals pl.qck. I tried using SqlFunctions.StringConvert but that isn't working either.

Comment: Ok it seems SQLFunctions isn't supported with oracle EF

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an explicit join?

```
from pl in location_table
join cs in q_table on cs.qk equals pl.qck
where s. att5 == 'process'
&& pl. location == 'there'
```